# Why is this form redirecting me before giving me a chance to enter data?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

Rails controller:

```
class VenuesController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @venue = Venue.new
  end

  def create
    @venue = Venue.new(params[:venue])
    if @venue.save
      redirect_to root_path
    end
  end

  def update
    redirect_to search_path
  end

end
```

Rails form:

```
<%= form_for(@venue) do |f| %>

  <%= f.text_field :foursquare_id %>

  <%= f.submit "Save" %>

<% end %>
```

"foursquare_id" is a column in the "venues" table. usually i import a foursquare id from foursquare but i'm typing in text for testing purposes. i am being redirected to "root_path" before even being given a chance to type into the form.

what is my controller/form missing? thank you in advance

Comment: Is this happening on modification or create (or both)?

Comment: Is the form's view template in right place and right name?

Comment: Do you have the chance to see the form? If yes, then do you use any kind of js in the view?

Comment: Are you hitting ENTER on the input before actually typing something?

Comment: On create. My view template is (I believe) in the right place (venues/create.html.erb). I thought I would have figured out Rails forms by this point...

Comment: Not hitting enter and not even given the chance to see the form (given my code above)!

Comment: No js in the view, not a remote form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The template form should be used by the `new` action with `new.html.erb` as the filename.  And you should be going to `/venues/new` to fill out the form.

The `create` action is used to submit the completed form, which is why you are getting redirected.  You should also modify `create` to handle a model that couldn't save:

```
def create
  @venue = Venue.new(params[:venue])
  if @venue.save
    redirect_to root_path
  else
    render :action => :new
  end
end
```

Or you can use the shorthand for this:

```
def create
  @venue = Venue.new(params[:venue])
  @venue.save
  respond_with @venue, :location => root_path
end
```

Comment: Thank you! Is there a particularly good reference for Rails forms somewhere, or would you simply look at guides.rubyonrails.org?

Comment: Aside from the guides (highly recommended), http://railscasts.com is a great resource.  There is also a popular tutorial by Michael Hartl - google is your friend.

Answer (score 0):

Your form for creating a new venue should be in venues/new.html.erb which will call the Create action in your controller upon form submit. You shouldn't have a create view in this scenario.